# Dealing with a user who just won't follow the rules

Tags: discussion, support, users

I would like to open by stating this user is not abusive or rude and I am not looking to get him banned or anything like that, I write this because he could be a good contributor.

The user has provided many, many (167) answers in a very short time.

Some of these answers are really bad. I tried on multiple occasions to point him in the right direction to creating good, useful answers but just cannot seem to get through.

He does not care about the quality of his answers and insists he is just helping people. I explained on multiple occasions that the point is to write good answers that can help many users, not to just answer as many easy ones as quickly as possible.

I have explained how this affects other users in review and how a duplicate vote is better than a link only answer that just gets down voted and violates the rules but he just won't seem to accept it.

I am now at a loss what to do about it, 900 rep (including 5 association bonuses @ 100 rep each) and 167 answers is by far the worst rep/answer ratio I have ever seen and is a clear indication that he is flooding the main page with bad answers that take up our reviewing time and help no one.

It feels a bit like I am telling on him or something but I don't want to have to keep reviewing these bad answers and don't want the site cluttered by rubbish every day, so what to do now? I tried but can't make him stop, any advice?

Comment: What I normally do is hound them *but* stay extremely polite.  [Just keep on hounding them](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbdsh.png): eventually you'll wear them down...  **;-)  :-)**

Comment: In the end, someone will get banned I believe.

Comment: I saw someone get banned the other for asking a (or more) question(s) that got to -10 very very quickly.  That was probably automatic.  You might PM Oli or Seth the username though.

Comment: You don't get more than one association bonus on a site.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Just keep doing standard review tasks on him - downvotes, delete votes, flags (where necessary), etc.

When he posts enough bad quality items, there is an automated system that will eventually make it harder for him to post.  Until then, his bad answers will continue to get him downvotes or get the posts deleted.

If he refuses to do higher quality posts, either because he doesn't know how, or is physically incapable of it - just continue to downvote him or delete-vote his posts, or flag his posts as "not an answer" when they're not answers within the context of the original question.

He'll either do something to fix the quality issues, or he won't - nothing we can do about it.  ***It is also not your job to make them listen to the rules*** - the "rules" for quality exist to make sure we get better quality answers, and when people don't follow those quality guidelines, they get downvotes or post removals.  This is how the system has run since the beginning - this is how the system should continue to run, with the users "trying their best" to help users, and just not helping them if they continue to screw up and not put forth effort.

Comment: For some reason we cried tears of blood to get those shinny tools enabled here...

Comment: @Braiam: you mean "shiny" as in "shiny with a metallic gleam to them, slick and sharp as razors" ? The kind you duly sterilize before and after each use ? Gee, I knew some'ing was up on AU ! I'm thinking about never asking a question again.... and I won't sign any discharge before being rolled in... and I want my lawyer.  ;-P

Comment: @Cbhihe just what's wrong with you?!

Comment: @Braiam: ... just felt a tiny bit facetious. Unfortunately the moment has passed. :-)